# Image appears next to text, but not when text is longer than one line

Tags: html, css, image

Image of the problem:

[image]

Codepen example of the problem: http://codepen.io/Mave/pen/PwBNKw

The image itself does not have any style applied to it.

```
.img{} (obligated to show at least one line of code here, stackoverflow rules)
```

What I want is the image to always be next to the text, never below it.
EDIT: Forgot to mention that it's not possible to move the image into the comment div because it's a Java project and I'm only doing front-end..

Comment: And what do you want? What is your question

Comment: @bbvanee I need the image to always appear next to the text, not below it.

Comment: apply display:inline-block on both content div as well as image

Comment: You are not just obligated to show one line of code, you should show a minimal, valid working example not just a link to an external site.  You even now have the option of pasting your codepen directly into the code windows on this site

Comment: @YogeshSharma that does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please paste your HTML how you are doing this?

Comment: @YogeshSharma I simply applied the display:inline-block code to both the image and the comment. The solution posted below works though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the image inside the comment-class, and put `float:right` on it:

HTML

```
<div class="comment"><img class="theimage" width="13" border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/KbsrwhT.png">
  Long comment Long comment Long comment Long comment Long comment Long comment Long comment Long comment Long comment Long comment 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.theimage{
    float:right;
}
```

See codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPjqrb

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it appears I have indeed no other choice than to move the image into the comment div. Thought there would be a way without moving the image into the div, but apparently there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you HTML is as given below then you don't need to do anything image will always come after content.

```css
.testing-demo {
display:inline;  
}
```

```html
    <div class="testing-demo">
     test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
    </div><img class="theimage" width="13" border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/KbsrwhT.png" />
```

Comment: Do you believe there is a method to do this without moving the image inside the div?

Comment: Yes, you can see example it's working it's a common feature if your content is not display:block and image as well then it will always come after content.

Comment: I found the solution: the comment does not need to be inline-block, but simply inline!

Comment: You can check image is outside of div and it's working